# Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid token: "me" An ID has already been specified

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

This is a new one to me, and I'm not sure why it is coming up. It only happens when I try to use the API to post a timeline action. I have the new Auth enabled, publish_actions is included in the permissions list, and I am the admin. I have uninstalled the app, and installed it again, to make sure the new auth has run through. If I run any other query with 'me', it will return just fine. But if I try to run the following:

$facebook->api('/me/example:read?chapter=http://www.example.com/og.php?og=read&id=24131', 'POST');

I get this error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid token: "me"  An ID has already been specified.

I am running it in ajax, so to make sure I have a valid access_token, I have var_dumped it and changed the line to read: $facebook->api('/me/friends'); In which case, I get valid output of my friends. So I have no clue what is causing this issue. I have also run a different ID (URL) each time, to make sure it isn't related to an action being posted twice (even though I got the error on the first try). Anyone else seeing this? Any clue why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two ? marks in your query string. You may need to urlencode the query string.

Comment: It worked! Thanks cmaxo. But now, Facebook can't read the url, as it is a attempting to use &amp; so the other parameter never comes up. In all of their examples they use something like example.com/cookies.html. htmlspecialchars and urlencode both break it. I guess I could replace it, but there should be a clean way to do it

Comment: So the &amp; thing is just fine. One other thing though, I needed to remove fb:page_id and og:site_url, and the debugger at least liked it. But I still get a different error about it being a og:type of website, when in fact, it isn't